# JS regex pathname match

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want is a simple check and match a path.

To clarify;

The application can have sub directories

```
/
/dashboard/modules
/modules/acounting/
/modules/acounting/stats
/modules/invoicing/
/modules/invoicing/invoices
```

What I want to accomplish is to match against everything from first forward slash to slash except the pages.

```
/
/dashboard/
/modules/acounting/
/modules/invoicing/
```

Tried //([^/]+)/[^/]*$/)

```
const url = window.location;
url.pathname.match(/\/([^/]+)\/[^/]*$/)
```

It creates a array. Regex help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `.*\/`

[Regex101 example and description](https://regex101.com/r/5vvaoO/1)

If you want to ***filter-match*** sections (vs. pages), use: `.*\/$`

[Regex101 example and description](https://regex101.com/r/SiEOFh/1)

Comment: can be as simple as that thanks!